# Ghost Exceptions: Java exceptions on empty lines

Tags: java, swing, exception

Well, I am trying to create an interface for a calculator. At this point, I have one button, a greeting label, and a label that will become the main line of the calculator. When I run the code, the window opens and the greeting is displayed, but the button is nowhere to be seen. The terminal displays:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

Cannot use this in a static context

    at Components.Interface.buttons(Interface.java:45)
    at Components.Interface.main(Interface.java:60)
```

The thing is, even if there is no code on lines 45 and 60, java still throws an exception for those lines. Why is it doing this? The code is below:

```
package Components;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Interface {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JFrame frame;
        JPanel text = new JPanel();
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel digits = new JLabel("");

        frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        frame.add(text);
        frame.add(controlPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
//about where line 45 is

        digits.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        digits.setSize(new Dimension(30, 20));

        text.add(digits);

        JLabel greet = new JLabel("Welcome to Calculator!");
        greet.setSize(30, 20);
        greet.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        greet.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        text.add(greet);
//about where line 60 is
        JButton one = new JButton("1");

        one.setSize(100, 30);

        one.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                digits.setText("1");
            }
        });
        controlPanel.add(one);
    }
}
```

Comment: A speedy response is never guaranteed. The better your question is, the faster/better response you'll receive. As well, make sure you've actually *compiled* your Java. When Java debugs (and resolves exceptions to line numbers), it doesn't *magically* know code has moved around until you re-compile that information into the .class files.

Comment: Your biggest mistake right now is that you're trying to run non-compilable code -- never do this! Instead find out what problems the compiler tells you about, not the JVM, and then try to fix them. Only try to run your code after it compiles without error.

Comment: "no code on lines 45 and 60" - we don't know what those lines are. You need to be more specific.

Comment: Added where the lines 45 & 60 are. The spacing is not exact, but the location between lines of code is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your biggest mistake right now is that you're trying to run non-compilable code -- never do this! Instead find out what problems the compiler tells you about, not the JVM, and then try to fix them. Only try to run your code after it compiles without error.

The compiler will then warn you that you're trying to use a non-final local variable, digits, within an anonymous inner class, and this isn't allowed. A solution is to declare digits as a final variable.

```
final JLabel digits = new JLabel ("");
```

You may ask why this strange requirement exists, well inner classes are true classes, even anonymous inner classes (like your ActionListener) and when Java creates one, it makes copies of local variables that are used by the inner class, and passes these copies into the inner class. If the variable is not final, the copy can get out of sync with the original.

Comment: I am using eclipse, and as far as I can tell, the files are automatically compiled when the "run" button is pressed. When I tell eclipse to build the program without running it, nothing happens. Am I just ignorant in the ways of java here, or is there something else wrong?

Comment: @RobintheSprite: I use Eclipse as well. So when just looking at your code in Eclipse and not running it, you should see red `x` in the left margin, and the problem view (I see it as a tab with my console view) should list all compilation errors and warnings including any for this program.

Comment: Aha! I installed Java 1.8 in my project by accident, and it was unbound. Eclipse did not like that (likely didn't know which library to use), so it couldn't build the program. All kinds of things are coming up now, which I will pick apart and fix. Thanks a lot, I was afraid of asking the internet because the internet is not always nice, but if a man names his account after a Monty Python reference, he must be alright.